Aren't there infinitely many ways to calculate the residue of a function at a pole?
Theorem 1 in the chapter about residue calculus in the complex analysis textbook by Saff and Snider says the following:
If $f$ has a pole of order $m$ at $z_0$, then
$$Res (f; z_0) = \frac{1}
{(m − 1)!} \lim_{z\to z_0}
\frac{d^{m−1}}
{dz^{m−1}}[(z−z_0)^m f(z)]$$.
I'm wondering if the condition of this theorem isn't unneccesary specific. My intuition tells me that we could replace it by a more general formulation, namely:
If $f$ has a removable singularity or a pole of order at most $m$ at $z_0$, then $...$
Would the theorem still be true with such an alteration if we kept everything else the same? I think that it would, and if I'm right, then there are infinitely many ways to calculate the residue of a function at a pole.
Let's assume that a particular function $g$ has a pole of order $5$ at the point $i$. If we wanted to calculate the residue of $g$ at $i$, then we could for example use the fact that (for this function and for this pole):
$$Res (g; i) = \frac{1}
{7!} \lim_{z\to i}
\frac{d^{7}}
{dz^{7}}[(z−i)^8 g(z)].$$
Do you agree?
$\Bbb Correction$
Actually we probably can't include the case of a removable singularity since it's unclear what m would mean then. Is a removable singularity a pole of order zero? If so, then what is the (-1)th derivative of a function?
However the theorem seems to remain true if we alter the original condition to:
If $f$ has a pole of order at most $m$ at $z_0$, then $...$
And I think that this would be the proper way to formulate the theorem. After reading the comments (which I appreciate), I still think that the original formulation is confusing. Perhaps a comparison can clarify why. The following is another true but confusing theorem, I would say:
If $n$ and $m$ are quadratic numbers then $n×m=m×n$.
The reason why it's confusing is that the commutative property has nothing to do with the property of being a sqare number. Analogously the equality in the mentioned theorem about residues doesn't hold because the pole has order m but because it has order at most m.
In my opinion, the proper way to formulate a theorem and the easiest way to calculate something are two different questions which should not be confused. A statement about the easiest way to calculate the residue of a function at a pole could have been added in the textbook after formulating the theorem in a more general and more appropriate way.

Why would you want to do that? Choosing $m$ in that formula larger than the order of the pole makes the computation more complicated.

As the answer says, yes, it's true. But notice that the result, as stated, is sharp, i.e. the order of the pole is the smallest $m$ for which the formula is valid. Even when we don't mention it, mathematicians like to make sharp statements.

@Martin R Maybe I don't want to do that. I just find the theorem confusing as it implicitly excludes a lot of computation methods which would work.

@JonathanZ Good point, but maybe the statement is sharpened so much that it has become confusing? If an obvious generalisation is not made, then the reader can start wondering if the more general statement is actually not true. Avoiding telling something can be telling in itself.

Why was the answer to my question deleted?  It seemed very good

While it's generally nice to think about generalizations, I don't know that omitting them makes this statement confusing, though that can vary from person to person. As for why this generalization isn't presented, I think MartinR is right: you'd have to do more work, and you don't get any new information.
